# What is the difference between [object main timeline], stage and root in as3?

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-3

I want to know the difference between `[object main timeline]`, `stage` and `root` in as3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a what seems to be a decent text covering the subject, it's linked to by several people:

[How stage, root, and MainTimeline Fit Together](http://cchoici.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-stage-root-and-maintimeline-fit.html)