# ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property box_mc_0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to hide movie clips from the stage using a loop, but I'm getting the following error when I publish it (this is just an example of the concept.)

```
var q;
for (q = 0; q <= 3; q++) {
   stage["box_mc_" + q].visible = false;
}
```

*The Error message:*

> *ReferenceError: Error #1069:* Property `box_mc_0` not found on
>   `flash.display.Stage` and there is no default value. at
>   `test_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()`

[image: ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property box_mc_0 not found on flash.display.Stage and there is no default value. at test_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to use the `this` keyword instead of the `stage` variable:

```
var q;
for (q = 1; q <= 3; q++) {
   this["box_mc_" + q].visible = false;
}
```

The simple reason being is that the objects are the children of a `MainTimeline` object, to which the `this` keyword would refer to in that context, and they are not the direct children of the `stage`.
If you're interested for more details on the difference, you may find useful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7346385/3709765).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @MikeP You're welcome, if you find the answer useful and it resolved your issue, please consider to [accept it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 1):

thats not realy child of stage,

if you try it, to tracing all of the stage childs

```
for (var i:int =0; i<stage.numChildren; i++) {
    trace(stage.getChildAt(i).name);
}
```

then you can see an intermediate container exists between `stage` and `box_mc_#` that's "root", because you added `box_mc_#` via time line

so in my case, the correct <del>call</del> way is

```
var q;
for (q = 0; q <= 3; q++) {
   stage.getChildByName("root1")["box_mc_" + q].visible = false;
}
```

Comment: @someOne wt? that's real answer to above question (with some little typo mistakes), also don't be fool with down vote button

Comment: There would be **another** _ReferenceError, Error #1069_, in your code while accessing the `stage["root1"]` for which you need to replace with `stage.getChildAt(0)` (regardless of your typo!), and the "down vote" button is there to make the things organized in this site :)

Comment: @someOne  thank you, but as you can see above, i said _**in my case**_ !!!!!!!!!!! and in the first code block a trace call provided the real name! that's not a constant, even i named it "root" there not "root1".

Comment: Your _specific_ case doesn't resolve the problem, but adds ambiguity to the issue by unintentionally conveying the concept incorrectly! Your code won't work, even if you remove the trailing number in `root1`!! i.e: the `stage.root` is not necessarily equal to the `stage.getChildAt(0)`, more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7346385/3709765) :)

Comment: Your [last edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40955961/revisions) is fine now and deserves taking back the "down vote" :)

Comment: @someOne thank you, now it works (just for avoiding an incorrect answer) but you'r right.